# Android modelling for feed screen

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I load a screen which has an endless scroll listener.  As the user scrolls down,  I make a network call and add the received list to current list.  Now let's say user has scrolled has very far down.  I keep on adding the list.  The list size would be huge.  I guess there could be performance issues maintaining that huge object.  How should I optimise this. Should I use database for this?  I am using recycler view for showing list.

Comment: use recyclerview with pagination.. recyclerview is built to optimise large list.

Comment: Pagination is not an option. All the apps like facebook, twitter, LinkedIn or any feed app, they have endless scroll listener